# Http Post Flutter to SAP

Tags: flutter

Im trying to use http post to transfer data from flutter to SAP. I can get data without any problem, but post attempt is failing with code 403 (x-csrf-token invalid)

I had the same problem while working in C# but that was resolved using event handler, that triggers just before save (please see below extract of C# code) but i'm unable to find option in flutter. Please guide..

```
   zZSSALE1SRVEntity.SendingRequest2 += new EventHandler<SendingRequest2EventArgs>(_container_SendingRequest_Enhance);
   zZSSALE1SRVEntity.SaveChanges();

   private void _container_SendingRequest_Enhance(object sender, SendingRequest2EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpWebResponse response;
        string empty = string.Empty;
        string str = string.Empty;
        CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        OdataSsaleDEV.ZZSSALE1_SRV_Entities zZSSALE1SRVEntity = new OdataSsaleDEV.ZZSSALE1_SRV_Entities(app_uri)
        {
            Credentials = credentials
        };
        string str1 ;
        if (empty == string.Empty)
        {
            HttpWebRequest credentials = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(zZSSALE1SRVEntity.BaseUri);
            credentials.Method = "GET";
            credentials.Headers.Add("X-CSRF-Token", "Fetch");
            credentials.Credentials = zZSSALE1SRVEntity.Credentials;
            cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            credentials.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)credentials.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (WebException webException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(webException.Message);
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
                return;
            }
            empty = response.Headers.Get("X-CSRF-Token");
            str = response.Headers.Get("Set-Cookie");
            credentials.Abort();
        }
        if (empty != string.Empty)
        {
            e.RequestMessage.SetHeader("x-csrf-token", empty);
            foreach (Cookie cooky in cookieContainer.GetCookies(zZSSALE1SRVEntity.BaseUri))
            {
                str1 = string.Concat(str1, ";", cooky.ToString());
            }
            e.RequestMessage.SetHeader("Cookie", str1.Substring(1));
        }
```

Comment: you can use http package. It is easy to use and should solve your problem

Comment: Yes i tried all, http, httpclient, dio i get same 403 error, where response body shows x-csrf-token validation failed. Im passing x-csrf-token in header. I call get method first for fetching token then pass it to post method

Comment: What i think, its session issue, as get and post are separate requests, may be session is not validating at server end, dont know how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.

Actually server requires session cookies (MYSAPSSO and SAP_SESSIONID) along with x-csrf-token.